# get value's from a datagridview from other form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, datagridview

HI,

Iam trying to get value's out of a datagridview.
this datagridview is on form one.

and where i want the value's is on form two;

but i dont want to do this :

[code]form1 frm = new from1();[/code]

because that form1 already exists so i dont want to create it again

can anytone plz help me get a solution for this
thank you very much

Comment: Hi Willem, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can access other open forms using the OpenForms collection on Application:

```
Application.OpenForms
```

Then all you need to do is test for the type or name of the form and cast it to your second form to grab the reference, then you can access its properties etc.

However, grabbing pieces of information like this across forms is considered bad design.  If the information can be aggregated out into something both forms can reference, this is better.  Alternatively, if the forms need to interact based on the state of each of their data, consider creating events between the two forms.

Comment: if i do this:

  <code>frmFactOverzicht frm = Application.OpenForms["frmFactOverzicht"];</code>

then it gives me this error 

Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.frmFactOverzicht'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\FB\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\InkFacturen\frmEditFact.cs 156 36 WindowsFormsApplication1

can you please help me with that?

Comment: You need to explicitly cast it: frmFactOverzicht frm = (frmFactOverzicht)Application.OpenForms["frmFactOverzicht"];

Answer (score 1):

Please don't even try to do that. Store your data in a data container object that is shared between the two forms. Bind form1 to the data and access it from form2.

Comment: I'll assume the -1 is you, there is no need for that - another interpretation of the question is how to access existing forms when you weren't given a reference.  I never said it was the best way to do it, nor did I advise it.

Comment: but can you please see my other post here in the topic

Comment: @willem I've answered the question you asked in the comments with another comment.

Answer (score 1):

in form1.designer.cs we have datagrid

```
    public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView GridOgrenci;
```

---

and form2 name yetkiler we can reach all form1 values

```
    public partial class Yekiler : Form
    {
    Utils Utility = new Utils();
    Form1 anaform = new Form1();

    public Yekiler()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Yekiler_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        anaform = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1;


        MessageBox.Show(anaform.GridOgrenci.ColumnCount.ToString());
```